# Project Web App - get Project ID from project related site via REST

Tags: rest, project-server, project-site

This is in SP2016 / Project Server 2016 on-prem.  (Also, full disclosure, my first experience with Project Server / PWAs.)

Let's say I have a PWA set up at the URL `http://servername/pwa/MyProjects`.  I set up the "Connected SharePoint Sites" to automatically create a project site when a project is published to the PWA.  Then I publish a project called "Project1".

Now I have a SharePoint site at the URL `http://servername/pwa/MyProjects/Project1`.

Is there a way to get the Project ID of the published project from the related SharePoint site, via SharePoint REST API?

Meaning, I want to use

```
http://servername/pwa/MyProjects/Project1/_api/web/Some-endpoint-I-don't-know
```

in order to get the ID of the related project so that I can then use

```
http://servername/pwa/MyProjects/_api/ProjectServer/projects('use-the-ID-here')
```

to get access to the project through the Project Server REST API.

I know it is there somewhere because on the QuickLaunch of the SharePoint site, there is a link to "Project Details" that has a URL of

```
http://servername/pwa/MyProjects/ProjectDrilldown.aspx?ProjUid=GUID-is-here&ret=1
```

Is there a way I can get the GUID without resorting to scraping the page?

Comment: Can i get the Uid in a local variabal workflow ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/94491)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/94491)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This applies for SharePoint Online/Project Online, however assuming it's the same for on-prem.

The Project GUID is stored as a site property called MSPWAPROJUID for the Project Site.

This is accessible using the /_api/Web/AllProperties end point.

ie. `http://servername/pwa/MyProjects/Project1/_api/Web/AllProperties`

### Using JS

```
 var ProjectUID;
 ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getProjectUIDProperty, "sp.js");

 function getProjectUIDProperty() { 
            var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
            this.web = ctx.get_web(); 
            this.props =  this.web.get_allProperties(); 
            ctx.load(this.web); 
            ctx.load(this.props);                    
            ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, gotProperty), Function.createDelegate(this, failedGettingProperty)); 
        }
         
function gotProperty() {                
             ProjectUID = this.props.get_item('MSPWAPROJUID');
        }
         
function failedGettingProperty() { 
            alert('Error: ' + args.get_message());
        }
```

### Using SPD

```
Set Variable:ps to [%Workflow Context:Current Site URL%]_api/Web/AllProperties/
```

Dictionary:

```
Accept: application/json; odata=nometadata
Content-Type: application/json; odata=nometadata
```

[image: SPD]