# Project Web App - get project related site from Project ID via REST

Tags: rest, project-server, project-site

My question is the exact opposite of [Project Web App - get Project ID from project related site via REST](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/224485/project-web-app-get-project-id-from-project-related-site-via-rest).

In that question, the user asked
*Is there a way to get the Project ID of the published project from the related SharePoint site, via SharePoint REST API?*

That's easily done, as the API exposes that GUID, but I haven't found the the opposite.

What I would like to do:

- **based on a project ID (GUID), get the related project site link**

The project site can be a random string that has no connection to the name of the project or its GUID and besides looping through all project sites on the server and comparing their `MSPWAPROJUID`'s to the one of a specific project, I haven't found anything useful so far.

Cheers.